# /etc/network/interfaces, systemd-networkd and NetworkManager: how do they coexist together?

Tags: networking, systemd, systemd-networkd

Is it sufficient to have one of these three in Ubuntu 19.04? Is it possible to have all three and how to configure them so they were not conflicting?

Does `systemd-networkd` started by networking.service?

Comment: @Fabby, 19.04. But this is general question (so imply latest version). The question is more appropriate for U&L, but I guessed AU is larger community.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you might know `/etc/network/interfaces` has been replaced with `netplan`. And `netplan` works fine with both `NetworkManager` and `systemd-networkd`.

So you can have them all work together!

If you're running Ubuntu as your desktop, then you should use `NetworkManager` or config `netplan` so it uses `NetworkManager` as its default renderer:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Otherwise you can easily setup your interfaces in `netplan` itself, for example to have `interfaces` like configuration and `network-manager` work together:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  wifis:
    wlp4s0:
      dhcp4: yes
      access-points:     
        my-access-point:
          password: passw00rd
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.10/24
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      gateway4: "192.168.1.1"
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - "8.8.4.4"
          - "8.8.8.8"
```

> #### Configuration
>
> To configure netplan, save configuration files under /etc/netplan/ with a .yaml extension (e.g. /etc/netplan/config.yaml), then run sudo netplan apply. This command parses and applies the configuration to the system. Configuration written to disk under /etc/netplan/ will persist between reboots.
>
> <sub>[Netplan configuration examples](https://netplan.io/examples)</sub>
>
> ---

Replacing netplan with `ifupdown` is still possible but something that I wouldn't suggests.

1. Install `ifupdown`
2. Remove `netplan`
3. Configure `interfaces`
4. Configure `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` so it would be able to manage your interfaces.
5. Restart networking services

You can even run `dhclient` directly to bring an interface up.

Comment: Where is netplan configured? You list a lot of configuration options but not where they go.